# How to make a character jump 100% of the time button is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I assigned the spacebar as jump key in my game but it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. Also there is a slight delay when the character jumps and button is pressed. The jump key is like a gamble in the game. Here's the script that i attached to the character.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MonsterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float walkStrength = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpStrength = 11f;

    private float movementX;
    private bool onCloud = true;
    private string CLOUD_TAG = "Cloud";
    private string WALK_ANIMATION = "walk";

    private Rigidbody2D mybody;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        mybody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        monsterWalk();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        monsterJump();
    }

    void monsterWalk()
    {
        movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        transform.position += walkStrength * Time.deltaTime * new Vector3(movementX, 0f, 0f);
    }

    

    void monsterJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && onCloud == true)
        {
            mybody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpStrength,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            onCloud = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(CLOUD_TAG))
        {
            onCloud = true;
            Debug.Log("Landed!");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the collider of my player thinking it might have got stuck with other collider. Again I trying changing the key thinking it was a problem of my keyboard but wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

In general: get single event input in `Update`!

If you check `GetKeyUp` within `FixedUpdate` - which is not called every frame - you might miss an Input.

So you should do e.g.

```
private bool isJump;

private void Update ()
{
    ...

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && onCloud)
    {
        isJump = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    ...
    
    if(isJump)
    {
        mybody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpStrength,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        onCloud = false;
        isJump = false;
    }
}
```

---

However, further

```
transform.position += walkStrength * Time.deltaTime * new Vector3(movementX, 0f, 0f);
```

is a problem as well when using a `Rigidbody`/`Rigidbody2D` since you completely overwrite the position here => the physics has no effect whatsoever so your adding force is good for nothing.

You also want to shift this into `FixedUpdate` and only go through the `myBody` here as well

```
private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    var movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * walkStrength * Time.deltaTime;

    // Keep Y velocity untouched and only overwrite X
    var vel = mybody.velocity;
    vel.x = movementX;
    mybody.velocity = vel:
}
```

as soon as physics is involved you do not want to get or set anything through the `Transform` component.